# NSIS doesn't detect previous version on certain x64 operating systems

Tags: nsis

I force an uninstall of the previous version prior to installing the new one.
For some reason, it does not work on XP/Vista/10 x64.  The uninstall string is blank.  I am nearly sure it is looking in the wrong registry.  is there a way to force it to check the non wow64 (or vice versa)?  I am at a loss as to what else it can possibly be.

```
# The ExecWait seems not to work on Windows XP x64/Vista x64/10 x64 (it seems to work fine on Vista x64/8 x64)
${If} ${RunningX64}
   ${GetWindowsVersion} $R0
   ReadRegStr $R1 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" "UninstallString"
   MessageBox MB_OK "You are running $R0 x64!  R1 is $R1"
   StrCmp $R1 "" no_remove_uninstaller
${Else}
  ${GetWindowsVersion} $R0
  ReadRegStr $R1 HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" "UninstallString"
  MessageBox MB_OK "You are running $R0 x86!  R1 is $R1"
  StrCmp $R1 "" no_remove_uninstaller
${EndIf}

  MessageBox MB_OKCANCEL|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION \
  "${PRODUCT_LONG_NAME} is already installed. $\n$\nIf you have software older than XXX 1.3, please manually uninstall it with Windows before proceeding. $\n$\nClick `OK` to remove the \
  previous version or `Cancel` to cancel this upgrade." \
  IDOK uninst IDCANCEL giveup

giveup:
  Abort

#  Run the uninstaller
uninst:
   ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\uninst.exe" _?=$INSTDIR' $R1
   StrCmp $R1 0 no_remove_uninstaller # Success? If so we are done...
   Abort # Uninstaller was canceled or failed, we cannot continue
```

**Edited**  - I removed the x64 functions above.  And made the changes you mentioned.  Due to the lack of InstallString I used the filefunc getparent function to do the test.  Should this do the trick or do I need to still do the regview?  It seems to work on XP x86 and 7 x64 though they always had worked.  Which made it odd that the in between OSes didn't.

```
ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" "UninstallString"
${GetParent} $0 $R0
IfFileExists "$R0\uninst.exe" 0 no_remove_uninstaller
ExecWait '"$R0\uninst.exe" _?=$R0' $R1
StrCmp 0 $R1 0 giveup
Delete "$R0\uninst.exe"
RMDir "$R0"
```

**Additional Update:** It still does not work on Vista x64 and XP x64.  Other flavours of Windows all work now.

**Last update** I think it works now... i swapped `regview 64` from `32` since my thinking of what i was doing was reversed.

Comment: Are you installing 64-bit specific components on 64-bit versions of Windows? If not, why do you have 64-bit specific code at all?

Answer (score 1):

You code does not make sense.

You are checking for `${RunningX64}` but still forcing it to access the 32-bit part of the registry. A 32-bit installer will always read from the 32-bit part of the registry unless you use `SetRegView 64`.

A bigger problem is that when running the uninstaller of a previous version you must use the previous versions path, not $InstDir! If your old versions write the InstallLocation value you can use that, otherwise you must extract the path from the UninstallString value. The important part is to remember that the previous install might be in a different directory than the one you end up installing to so you must also do some extra cleanup:

```
ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" "InstallLocation"
IfFileExists "$0\uninst.exe" 0 no_previous_version
ExecWait '"$0\uninst.exe" _?=$0' $R1
StrCmp 0 $R1 0 uninst_aborted
Delete "$0\uninst.exe"
RMDir "$0"
```

Comment: I also don't have `installpath` in my uninstall section.  Which can be alleviated by using uninstring and deleting the `\uninst.exe` from the string.  But I also then lose the dialogue box though i suppose it is redundant.